# How SearchView with collapseActionView just display icon Instead of title?

Tags: android, searchview

The source problem : I want to collapse `SearchView` when I submit the query ,so i have to set the `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"` . Because `MenuItem.collapseActionView` must have this properties . The menu layout is :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/photo_search"
        android:title="@string/photo_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"></item>
</menu>
```

But it only shows the title instead of search icon :
[image: The wrong image]

But what i want is this (This happens when i remove `collapseActionView` in `app:showAsAction`):
[image: The expected image]

So how do i get the expected result when i add `collapseActionView` properties which i have to ?